# when using JUNIT 4.8 categories , the report generated does not show the actual class how to overcome this?

Tags: testing, junit, grouping

i m new to junit and i used testNg before

i use junit 4.8 categoreis feature to group my test cases and when i generate the report using test cases it only shows the "SuiteClass" that i have used to run the categorized test cases as the Main class that test methods are written .
No actual class that methods actually written are not displayed in the report.
this make me to go through all the test classes that i have categorized in a particular category to find the failed test method .

isnt there any solution to over come this matter ???

ps: i run test cases by passing the fully quallified name of the SuiteClass to an ant script

thank you